# “yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>” How to get repoid for centos 7?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I mistaken installed *centos7 minimal*. But I want to install GUI for Centos 7.From [this link](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-gnome-gui-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html#axzz3akuzDgRj), I try the following commands:

```
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"
```

But It is asking *repoid*, like:

```
yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>.
```

I don't know the *repoid*. How to get *repoid* for Centos 7?

Answer (score 5):

- `yum repolist all` - to see the repos you have (enabled / disabled)
- `yum repolist` - list all enabled Yum repositories in your system
- `yum repolist -v` - Enabled Repositories with Details

**For reference:**

- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-config-manager.1.html